# Find the PDF of X1 +X2 +X3.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

The problem said:

> If X1,X2,X3 are independent random variables that are uniformly
>   distributed on (0,1), find the PDF of X1 +X2 +X3.

The theory I have said:

[image]

Following the theory and the example for the sum of two random variables, I try to set up the integral, therofore:

> $f_{X_1}(a)=f_{X_2}(a)=f_{X_3}(a)= 1$ when $0 < a < 1$ and $0$ otherwise ;

I belive the region of the integral will be a cube of $1 x 1 x 1$, then:

$$P((X_1\leq x_1, X_2\leq x_2, X_3\leq x_3) = \iiint_{\Bbb [0;1]^3} f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) \;\mathrm d\,x_1 \;\mathrm d\,x_2 \;\mathrm d\,x_3$$

because are independient I have and from the definition of convolution the pdf is:

> $$f_{X_1+X_2+X_3}(a)= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f_{X_1}(a-x_2-x_3) f_{X_2}(x_2) f_{X_3}(a-x_2)\;\mathrm d\,x_2 \;\mathrm d\,x_3$$

Well I am stuck in this part, as I have no idea how to calculate the correct PDF of X1,X2,X3 fx1,x2,x3 from here or if all my procerdure is wrong.**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are each restricted to values in the interval $(0,1)$, to calculate the pdf of $X_1+X_2+X_3,\; f(a),$ there are different cases depending on $a$ as it ranges over its possible values from $0$ to $3$.

You may like to plot in 3D the plane $x+y+z=a$ for various $a$ values to see why this is and also to determine the limits of integration (though it can be done without plotting).

For $0\leq a\leq 1$:

\begin{align}
f(a) &= \int_{x_2=0}^{a} \int_{x_3=0}^{a-x_2} f_1(a-x_2-x_3)f_2(x_2)f_3(x_3)\;dx_3\;dx_2 \\
&= \int_{x_2=0}^{a} \int_{x_3=0}^{a-x_2} 1\;dx_3\;dx_2 \\
& \\
&= a^2/2.
\end{align}

The individual pdfs in the integrands are always just $1$ so we use that from here on.

For $1\lt a\leq 2$:

\begin{align}
f(a) &= \int_{x_2=0}^{a-1} \int_{x_3=a-1-x_2}^{1} 1\;dx_3\;dx_2\; +\; \int_{x_2=a-1}^{1} \int_{x_3=a}^{a-x_2} 1\;dx_3\;dx_2 \\
& \\
&= -a^2 + 3a - 3/2.
\end{align}

For $2\lt a\leq 3$:

\begin{align}
f(a) &= \int_{x_2=a-2}^{1} \int_{x_3=a-1-x_2}^{1} 1\;dx_3\;dx_2 \\
& \\
&= a^2/2 - 3a + 9/2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks!...If I want to check that it is correct and that is a pdf, then I need to calculate the integral  between 0 and 1 dx1 , 1 and 2  dx2, 2 and 3 dx3 and that must be 1 no??? Thanks, again.

Comment: @JulietaR Yes, if you mean check that $$1=\int_0^1 x^2/2\;dx+\int_1^2 (-x^2+3x-3/2)dx+\int_2^3 (x^2/2-3x+9/2)dx.$$ Also check that this function is non-negative for all $0\leq x\leq3,\;$ which it is :-).